# ESP8266 wake up from deep sleep on air flow

Tags: esp8266, sleep

I am building a small device using ESP8266 and battery power (low power), as I would like to clip it to an air vent and have it wake up from deep sleep when the air vent is blowing, take measurements, and then put it back to sleep.
I learned that EXT_RSTB pin via an external IO can wake up the chip from deep-sleep. I saw a post here about using light change as a wake up.
I believe I have to send a high signal through the RST pin, but I am at a loss on which sensor I could buy to detect the air movement from the vent and send this signal.  I looked at the Piezo Vibration Sensor SEN-09197, but I don't know if that is going to do it.
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: you can just use a microphone to detect airflow, that's how i log my furnace. The problem for you is keeping the sensor powered.